# Run command dependent on OS and IF service is present

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0

I have 2 scripts as follows that gets websites for IIS.

IIS 6 -

```
$website = Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" | Select ServerComment | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-file c:\website.txt
$b = Get-Content -Path C:\website.txt
$b | ForEach {$_.TrimEnd()} | ? {$_.trim() -ne '' } > C:\website.txt
$b = Get-Content -Path C:\website.txt
@(ForEach ($a in $b) {$a.Replace(' ', '')}) > C:\website.txt
Get-Content C:\website.txt
```

IIS 7+

```
Import-Module webadministration
$a = Get-Website | Select-Object Name
$a | ForEach-Object { 
$_.name = $_.name.replace(" ","")
}
$a | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File $DeviceDrive\Apps\NetprobeNT\Auto-monitor\Website.txt
$b = Get-Content -Path $DeviceDrive\Apps\NetprobeNT\Auto-monitor\Website.txt
$b | ForEach {$_.TrimEnd()} | ? {$_.trim() -ne '' } > $DeviceDrive\Apps\NetprobeNT\Auto-monitor\Website.txt
$b = Get-Content -Path $DeviceDrive\Apps\NetprobeNT\Auto-monitor\Website.txt
@(ForEach ($a in $b) {$a.Replace(' ', '')}) > $DeviceDrive\Apps\NetprobeNT\Auto-monitor\Website.txt
```

I have a different script for IIS 6 (Windows 2003 hosts) because webadministration module is not available for II6.

I need to add an `if` statement that will add logic to run the correct code dependent on the host operating system and if W3SVC service (World Wide Web Publishing Service) is present (running or stopped). Something along the lines

```
IF W3SVC is present
  Check host operating system
  IF operating system = Windows 2003
    Run II6 code
  Else
    Run II7+ code
```

I don't know where to begin with this script. PowerShell and scripting is new to me and this is part of my first script I am creating. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I can get the host operating system but confused on how I would put logic into it to get the results I need.

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Caption` rather than `Name`. Other than that you simply plug the routine into your pseudocode:

```
if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eq 'Windows 2003') {
  # Run II6 code
} else {
  # Run II7+ code
}
```

For the service you can use the `Get-Service` cmdlet:

```
if (Get-Service -Name w3svc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
  ...
}
```

or `Get-WmiObject` on the `Win32_Service` class if the `Get-Service` cmdlet isn't available in PowerShell v2 (not sure about that):

```
if (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name='w3svc'") {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, Would that work for different versions of Windows 2003 hosts, i.e Windows 2003 service pack 2. Would it not need a * anywhere? Also How do I combine to IF statements together?

Comment: You need a wildcard match if you need to handle different Windows Server editions (like Standard and Enterprise). Service pack information shouldn't show up in the caption. As for combining the statements: consider that your homework. Shouldn't be too hard since you already have the pseudocode.

Comment: Just tested combining. I put an IF statement inside the 1st IF statement. Ive tried to put Windows 2003* but keep getting false. Am I using wild card correctly?

Comment: Did you change the operator? You need to use `-like` instead of `-eq` for wildcard matches.

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers, that worked. I tested the following on a 2008 host -  if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -like " * Windows server 2008 * "). Just to confirm does wild cards work before the word? It seems to be working